# firefox localStorage undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage

In Firefox i get weird behavior, when i try (anywhere even in firebug cosnole)

```
function supports_local_storage() {
    try {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
    } catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}

var localStorageEnabled = supports_local_storage();
if (!localStorageEnabled) { 
    alert('am in');
    console.log('am in');
    var localStorage = localStorage;
};
localStorage.setItem("textsfff", "20");
```

..
In case localStorage is enabled in firefox, so no alert/console log is poped out, but localstorage is destoryed by unknow process, so setItem fails.

If i rewrite

```
var localStorage = localStorage;
```

to

```
localStorage = localStorage;
```

Code miraculously works, its like localstorage is deleted when "var localstorage" is present anywhere in code, even if condition is not met.

Am getting this problem inly in firefox 29.0.1

I cant use

localStorage = localStorage;

because in console mode i have to define localstorage myself and need "var declaration".

Comment: `localStorage = localStorage;` doesn't do anything, just as `var x; x = x;` doesn't do much.

Comment: what do you mean with 'because in console mode i have to define localstorage myself and need "var declaration"' ?

Comment: mb21 - in console mode localstorage does not exist, so i have make own one and set it to localStorage variable. But since of MrCode explanation, var reedefinition in condition is runned even if condition is not true .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> its like localstorage is deleted when "var localstorage" is present anywhere in code, even if condition is not met.

The `localStorage` object is in the global scope, and a property of the `window` object. If you use `var localStorage` then you can no longer access the global `localStorage` object from that scope - unless you use the `window` prefix like so:

```
window.localStorage.getItem(..);
```

This is indeed the case, even if your condition is not met because all `var` declarations are hoisted to the top of the current scope, regardless of any conditional statements. The code is equivalent to:

```
var localStorage;

if(!localStorageEnabled){
    localStorage = localStorage; // this is undefined
}
```

So when you do `var localStorage = localStorage`, the local variable `localStorage` is declared but not defined, at the top of the current scope, then you are assigning `undefined` to the local `localStorage`. This is why `localStorage = localStorage` works without the `var`, because without the `var` it is finding the global object.

> I cant use `localStorage = localStorage;` because in console mode i have to define localstorage myself and need "var declaration".

In that case, you can use the `window` prefix for when localStorage is present/enabled.

```
var localStorage = window.localStorage;
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, that made prety clear what happened. But am still stuck since after `var localStorage = localStorage;` in firefox also `window.localStorage` is undefined so i cant set it back or use it . I tried `eval("var localStorage = 10");`  , that worked for firefox but crashed in console mode where i continue with setting custom class to localStore variable.

Comment: I think you need an `else` block so you can do `else { localStorage = window.localStorage; }`. In the if block, it seems you should be setting it to your custom object.

Comment: I accepted your answer, since it made clear redefining localStorage with "var" definition its just bad idea and cause totall crash in ff. By console i meaned js runned throught node `$result = exec("node -e {$jsContent})` , my final solution was just to take off whole part from shared js and add it separately to $jsContent only when running test.